# Approximation of Sobolev space functions by smooth functions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I am learning about the Sobolev spaces from the book "Theoretical numerical analysis : a functional analysis framework" by Atkinson and Ham.

Here is the excerpt from the book that I do not understand:

[image]

I do not understand the part that says "Since $C^\infty(\overline\Omega) \subset C^k(\overline\Omega) \subset W^{k,p}(\Omega) $". Why do we need to say anything about the space "$C^k(\overline\Omega)$" ?

Isn't it sufficient to say just that"Since $C^\infty(\overline\Omega) \subset W^{k,p}(\Omega) $. "?

Comment: It sure looks that way. But it depends on what has been developed previously in this textbook

Comment: @HansEngler Do you mind telling me what I am missing??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The author just wanted to be more clear about the reason for inclusion:

$u\in C^\infty(\overline{\Omega}) \implies $ $u$ has continuous classical derivatives of orders up to $k$ $\implies $ $u$ has weak derivatives of orders up to $k$, which are in  $L^p$.

The implications are expressed as inclusions, the middle step being $u\in C^k(\overline{\Omega})$.